# Fail to point my domain through the resolv.conf file

Tags: 18.04, dns, resolv.conf, domain-server

I'm trying to connect my domain with my Ubuntu 18.04 server through the resolv.conf file.

I add the domain on cloudflare (it is already active) I create an A record to point the server IP and then I add those lines in the resolv.conf file.

resolv.conf

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

domain forrum.ro
glen.ns.cloudflare.com 62.210.69.189
zoe.ns.cloudflare.com 62.210.69.189
#search online.net
```

Please help me to find out why it isn't working. I did something wrong or I miss something?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you're adding it to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

That's not how DNS works. To configure the nameservers for the domain, you should contact your registrar for information on how to configure DNS. This varies from domain registrar to domain registrar, and is a record housed in the DNS system, which you cannot modify directly. You **have** to go trough your registrar.

To configure a host on DNS, you then configure a record on the nameservers you have assigned, in this case Cloudflare, that points to the IP of your server.

Comment: The domain registrat already changed the nameservers to glen and zoe.ns.cloudflare.com

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To connect my domain with my server.

Comment: Then create an A (IPv4) or AAAA (IPv6) record at cloudflare.

Comment: To point it to my server ip address right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I already did it, but still not working.

Comment: What is the domain? It may take some time before updates are visible (order of hours).

Comment: Up to 24 hours, depending on the registrar.